# Query XML file with PHP to return certain bookmarks

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have an XML file full of bookmarks from Google Bookmarks. (File: http://gist.github.com/324844) I want to pull the bookmark based on this path: xml_api_reply->bookmarks-bookmark->labels->label.

So, my question is How can I use SimpleXML to grab the bookmarks that have the label Inspiration? Some bookmarks may have more than one bookmark.

EDIT: The file listed above is just a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for that.

The nodes you want:

```
/xml_api_reply/bookmarks/bookmark
```

The filter you want to apply:

```
[labels/label = "Inspiration"]
```

Gives you the following XPath query:

```
/xml_api_reply/bookmarks/bookmark[labels/label = "Inspiration"]
```

Used in a script:

```
$xml_api_reply = simplexml_load_file('http://gist.github.com/raw/324844/e4b1e05118b09c61c2a5b8b9a3bab92b895de07c/GoogleBookmarksXMLOutput');

foreach ($xml_api_reply->xpath('/xml_api_reply/bookmarks/bookmark[labels/label = "Inspiration"]') as $bookmark)
{
    // ...
    echo $bookmark->asXML();
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the shorter `//bookmark[labels/label = "Inspiration"]` -- see that [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)